# How to create a gradient that goes across different rectangles in D3JS?

Tags: d3.js, svg

In D3JS V4: Suppose that you have six rectangles. How would you create a gradient that flows through from the first to the last?

[image: Gradient across bars]

I tried creating a group for the rectangles and then add the color-gradient-id to the group, but it still causes for the gradient to happen within each rectangle individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `gradientUnits` to `userSpaceOnUse`. According to the docs, [userSpaceOnUse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/gradientUnits):

> ...represent values in the coordinate system that results from taking the current user coordinate system in place at the time when the gradient element is referenced

Here is a demo without `userSpaceOnUse`, which result is not what you want:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var gradient = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "gradient")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "50%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y2", "50%");

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "0%")
  .attr("stop-color", "Black")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", "white")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .style("fill", "url(#gradient)");

var rects = g.selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(7))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 20 + 50 * i)
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400"></svg>
```

Now a demo with `userSpaceOnUse`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var gradient = svg.append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "gradient")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "50%")
  .attr("x2", "100%")
  .attr("y2", "50%")
  .attr("gradientUnits","userSpaceOnUse");

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "0%")
  .attr("stop-color", "Black")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "100%")
  .attr("stop-color", "white")
  .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .style("fill", "url(#gradient)");

var rects = g.selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(7))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("x", (d, i) => 20 + 50 * i)
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400"></svg>
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo! Yes, that one line of code did the trick! I just added ".attr("gradientUnits","userSpaceOnUse");"  where I defined my gradient, and that fixed the issue! Thank you so much!